# Will my new Dell laptop come with a 'real' Windows Vista DVD?

Tags: windows, dell-vostro

I am considering buying a Dell Vostro laptop.  When I get it, I'd prefer to reformat it with a fresh, clean install of the OS.  Will it come with a DVD that will allow me to do this, or will it come with some sort of restore cd that will reinstall all the crap I'm trying to get rid of?

Answer (score 2):

The drivers and all the other utilities were on separate DVDs from the Vista install disk for my dell. It should be a 'real' Vista DVD.

Answer (score 2):

The last Dell I bought came with an OEM install DVD, none of this restore rubbish. Assuming they haven't changed, it should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you select to include the media in your purchase (if you're shopping online). Most laptop companies are now shipping without any kind of CDs by default, and instead sticking the restore information into a small partition on the harddrive.

As stated by @ezwi, the "media" option will give you the installation DVD instead of a restore DVD.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will allow you to do this.

If you get the "media" it is just an OEM installation DVD.  Not a silly restore DVD.

You also get a separate CD with the drivers on it.

Answer (score 1):

Dell have different policies for different markets, from my experience they do ship with a OS installation DVD, however, to be sure to be sure, ring them up and ask a sales rep whether the Vista DVD is included in the deal.

if it isn't, hinting that you may buy elsewhere works miracles. :)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the whole point of the 'Vostro' line is that *you don't have to do a clean install* - you're actually paying for a clean install of the OS with no pre-installed crapware (that's what the 'Vostro' bit means).

...and my Dell laptop came with a proper Vista install CD (though its almost 2 years old now).